# How to create a new document (Resource) from PHP

Tags: php, modx, modx-revolution

I would like to create an automated system that creates new Document (Resources Pages) using PHP instead of the UI. However I cant find any tutorial on how to do that from PHP.

Does anyone know how could I do that or if I can do that?

I am using Modx Revolution

Comment: Have you checked the [documentation](http://rtfm.modx.com/revolution/2.x/developing-in-modx/advanced-development/custom-resource-classes/creating-a-resource-class)?

Comment: That link is for creating custom resource classes, not the resources themselves

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
$resource = $modx->newObject('modResource');
$resource->fromArray(array(
    'pagetitle' => 'My Resource Title',
    // add other resource properties here
));
$resource->save();
```

There are some forum posts and articles out there that will help you with this, if you Google hard enough...

Comment: +1 there are many threads outlining exactly how to do this: http://forums.modx.com/thread/?thread=31314&page=1